# The network adapter on which the capture was being done is no longer running

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors

I am working with Ubuntu OS and using Wireshark to capture wireless traffic. And I can enable the monitor mode, but now the problem is a pop up  message is coming and what should I do?  It will stop to capture. How to remove this message.
I can enable monitor mode without using aircrack-ng. I put this commands ...

```
sudo ifconfig wlp6s0 down
sudo iwconfig wlp6s0 mode monitor 
iwconfig
sudo ifconfig wlp6s0 up


naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~$ iwconfig
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your command is wrong and the interface you want to work with is in managed mode. It should be like this(if not in root mode):

```
sudo airodump-ng mon0
```

Or if you also want a specific output file.

```
sudo airodump-ng -w output.txt mon0
```

Besides, once you have a virtual interface in monitor mode, you can just fire up wireshark and select `mon0` and you'll see all the traffic it can capture but it will be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for the support. now I can enable monitor mode without using aircrack-ng.  but there is a pop message is comeing .Do you know what is the solution for this ? I edit my question please check